# Change url but keep some layout elements

Tags: jquery-mobile

There's a way to call another page (changing url) but keep some layout elements without refresh like facebook chat or Groovshark player?

I'm making use of the native ajax change page system of the jmobile:

```
<a href="otherpage.html" data-transition="pop">Go</a>
```

Is working ok with a cool transition but the navbar is doing the effect too. I want the navbar keep static, i think is possible do it loading the new page into another "div page" but this way the url dont change and i need url be changed

Comment: show some more code of your page

Answer (score 0):

add to your header / footer section:

`data-position-fixed="true"`

and use the same id for header / footer on both sites. jqm will recognize that the elements are equal and doesn't animate them during the transition.

To change the url you can use:

`<div data-role='page' id='foo' data-url='http://mynewurl.com/123' />`